# Terminate called after throwing an instance of an exception, core dumped

Tags: c++, c++11, exception

I am going over C++ exceptions and am running into an error that I am unsure of why it is giving me issues:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <exception>

 class err : public std::exception
 {
 public:
      const char* what() const noexcept { return "error"; }
 };

 void f() throw()
 {
      throw err();
 }

 int main()
 {
      try
      {
           f();
      }
      catch (const err& e)
      {
           std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
      }
 }
```

When I run it, I get the following runtime error:

```
 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'err'
   what():  error
 Aborted (core dumped)
```

If I move the `try/catch` logic completely to `f()`, i.e.

```
 void f() 
 {
      try
      {
           throw err();
      }
      catch (const err& e)
      {
            std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
      }
 }
```

And just call it from `main` (without the try/catch block in main), then there is no error.  Am I not understanding something, as it relates to throwing exceptions from functions?

Comment: `void f() throw()` says that the function _doesn't_ throw exceptions. And then you do.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: It's not _undefined behavior_ to throw from such a function; you call `std::unexpected`.  That's just probably not something you _want_.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `throw()` in `void f() throw()` is a [dynamic exception specification](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/except_spec) and is deprecated since c++11. It's was supposed to be used to list the exceptions a function could throw. An empty specification (`throw()`) means there are no exceptions that your function could throw. Trying to throw an exception from such a function calls [`std::unexpected`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/unexpected) which, by default, terminates.

Since c++11 the preferred way of specifying that a function cannot throw is to use [`noexcept`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec). For example `void f() noexcept`.

Comment: Thank you! I had an incorrect understanding.  It looks like `noexcept(false)` will provide the same functionality and looks to not have been deprecated

Comment: @HectorJ `noexcept(false)` is the default for most functions and usually does not need to be provided. I believe destructors are `noexcept(true)` by default and as far as I know that would be the only time `noexcept(false)` has meaning (though that's not recommended).